# SQL select a specific row based on key when performing a select distinct / group by

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a dataset that resembles the following:

```
|   ID    |   Match1    |   Match2    |    Key     |     Val1   |
|   1     |     a       |    b        |     a      |      a     | 
|   2     |     a       |    b        |     c      |      b     |
|   3     |     a       |    b        |    keep    |      c     |
|   4     |     a       |    a        |     a      |      d     |
```

You'll see rows 1-3 have matching values in Match1 and Match2, and row 3 has "keep" in the Key column.

I'm trying to write a query that will drop rows 1 and 2 based on matching criteria, but keep row 3 because of the key provided. The resulting dataset would look as follows:

```
|   ID    |   Match1    |   Match2    |    Key     |     Val1   |
|   3     |     a       |    b        |    keep    |      c     |
|   4     |     a       |    a        |     a      |      d     |
```

Any suggestions for how to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me *guess* that you want one row per `match1`/`match2` combo, with preference for the "keep".  If so:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.id = (select t2.id
              from t t2
              where t2.match1 = t.match1 and t2.match2 = t.match2
              order by (key = 'keep') desc,  -- highest preference for "keep"
                       id desc               -- most recent id
              limit 1
             );
```

To handle `NULL`s you can use a `NULL`-safe comparison:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.id = (select t2.id
              from t t2
              where t2.match1 <=> t.match1 and t2.match2 <= >t.match2
              order by (key = 'keep') desc,  -- highest preference for "keep"
                       id desc               -- most recent id
              limit 1
             );
```

Comment: Yes, that's a better way to word it! The subquery returns multiple results, so I had to add a `LIMIT 1`. I also had to add conditions to check for NULL values. Ex: `where (t2.Match1 = t.Match1 or (t2.Match1 is NULL and t.Match2 is NULL))`. After making those changes, this solution worked. Can you update your response, and I'll mark as answered?

Comment: @DylanMiller . . . The `limit 1` is pretty central to the subquery.  I added a version with a `NULL`-safe comparison.